# Consuming XML response from a REST call in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Seems to be a simple task but I cannot get my head around it.

I have a Spring integration chain which calls an external Webservice, which returns an XML. I would like to use that XML response in a downstream XpathRouter.

What expected-response-type should I use?

```
<int:chain input-channel="filesChannel">

    <!-- ... some previous components in the chain -->
    <int-http:outbound-gateway
        http-method="POST"
        url="http://web/service/url"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" />

    <int-xml:xpath-router default-output-channel="resultChannel">
        <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="/order/status" />
        <int-xml:mapping value="Error" channel="importErrorChannel" />
    </int-xml:xpath-router>
</int:chain>
```

It doesn't seem like the `xpath-router` can consume the XML returned by the webservice. When I debug the router with a breakpoint on the following line:

```
    Node node = this.converter.convertToNode(message.getPayload());
```

The node is null, although the message does contain valid XML.

Is it because I am not setting the right `expected-response-type`?

Here is the response XML I receive from the service:

```
<apiResponse version="1.0">
<orders>
<order>
       <orderReference>test_2_3045342</orderReference>
       <status>Error</status>
       <errors>
          <error>
              <errorCode>1100</errorCode>
              <errorMessage><![CDATA[ "Field is required: dropWindow" ]]></errorMessage>
          </error>
       </errors>
</order>
</orders>
</apiResponse>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistake - it was actually in the XPATH expression. It should have been `//order/status` to enable deep search.

The `java.lang.String` expected-response-type works just fine with XML XpathRouter.

Thanks